# Android - Unicode filenames in assets/

Tags: android, unicode

I have some unicode filenames in assets such as "heiß". And the following code to grab the file returns an IOException. Are unicode filenames not supported or is there something else I can do?

```
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("heiß");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think unicode filenames are not supported in assets folder.. i usually seen to add fonts in assests folder.. and those fonts are retreiving through corresponding java class